# Disabling shortcuts in insertion mode with vim bindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am quite new to vscode, and am trying to figure out how to solve the following issue:

1. I use vim bindings (via vscodevim), and am happy with it
2. I have custom bindings for the main language I develop in (Coq) that I am adamant about keeping and that are of the form ", n", ", u" and so on. These shortcuts are not used to edit code, but rather to interact with the prover.

This setup currently entails that I globally cannot type a comma anymore, which is quite annoying :) I hence would like to disable these shortcuts when in insertion mode.

I have tried to add the condition `!vim.insertModeKeyBindings` to all `When` fields of these custom bindings, but it does not seem to be sufficient: pressing , still triggers a `Waiting for second key of chord...` even in insertion mode.

Would anyone know how to solve this issue by any chance?

Best,

Yannick